# dependant HTTP Get

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to make a HTTP get after an another HTTP get which take an info of the first HTTP get for his header. My code is angular 2 Typescript with observables.

Can you give snippet or other response elements ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage the `flatMap` operator of observable:

```
return this.get('someurl').flatMap(res => {
  var header = res.headers.get('Some-Header');
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Some-Header', header);
  return this.get('otherurl', { headers }).map(res => res.json());
});
```